# HTTP custom Header key name in Non-english Language

Tags: http, http-headers

Is it possible to provide the HTTP custom header name in request or response header in other than the English language?
In our case, we are integrating our service with external servers and, we want to take the Header name "which external server will be responding as Auth Header" as input from the user. If there is an option to provide header-name in Chinese or other languages.

1. we would require it to be validated for Non-Ascii character.
2. Otherwise we can restrict users to only use the English language.

Answer (score 2):

No, field names are restricted to a subset of US-ASCII. See https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#header.fields for details.